# Cannot execute Python game

Tags: python, pygame

I have a game which was programmed on Python 2 apparently, and I need to change it to python 3 code style. I'm a beginner on this so there's a lot I don't know. So far the only thing I could change was the prints which only needed parenthesis. My current problem is the following:

```
File "A:\Descargas\GalacticWars\GalacticWars\galacticWars.py", line 984, in <module>
main()
File "A:\Descargas\GalacticWars\GalacticWars\galacticWars.py", line 979, in main
escena.update()
File "A:\Descargas\GalacticWars\GalacticWars\galacticWars.py", line 102, in update
funcion()
File "A:\Descargas\GalacticWars\GalacticWars\galacticWars.py", line 150, in nuevo_juego
escena = Game()
File "A:\Descargas\GalacticWars\GalacticWars\galacticWars.py", line 554, in __init__
  self.record = pickle.load(self.records)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The lines have this:

984 and 985

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

976 to 981

```
# Bucle principal.
while True:
    # Actualizamos la escena.
    escena.update()
    escena.imprimir(screen)
    clock.tick(60)
```

89 to 102:

```
    def update(self):
    # Altera la opción seleccionada con las teclas cursor.
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if not self.mantiene_pulsado:
        if key[K_UP]:
            self.seleccionado -= 1
        elif key[K_DOWN]:
            self.seleccionado += 1
        elif key[K_RETURN]:
            # Invoca a la función asociada a la opción-
            titulo, funcion = self.opciones[self.seleccionado]
            print 'Selecionando función:', repr(titulo)
            funcion()
```

146 to 150:

```
# Función para comenzar el nuevo juego.
def nuevo_juego():
# Pasamos la variable global escena.
global escena
escena = Game()
```

552 to 556:

```
# Vamos a otener el Hi-score.
    self.records = open('records', 'r')
    self.record = pickle.load(self.records)
    self.records.close()
    print 'Cargando Record:', self.record
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python 2's str is of type "bytes".
python 3's str is of type "unicode".

the short, irresponsible answer would be:

change `self.records = open('records', 'r')`

to `self.records = open('records', 'rb')`

the long, responsible answer would be:

read about the topic and handle it in a way which would be proper for ALL your code

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked, still got a whole lot bunch of other problems but i managed to solve them so far.